# How to make a patch for C Library

Tags: 12.04, glibc, vulnerability

For my class project, I am trying to fix a ghost vulnerability on Ubuntu 12.04 manually. I completely understand the errors inside the /nss/digits_dots.c and I fixed them. My problem is I don't know how to make a patch and compile it.
How can I do a patch? How can I just edit one file in the library and re-build it? I was able to download the source library, but then I got stuck! Here is what I did

```
apt-get source libc6
```

I had some errors. Then I had to install other packages like

```
sudo apt-get install alien
sudo apt-get install gawk
```

But after that I started several things and started to go into circles and loops, but with no success. Can someone please tell me how to do a simple patch for a C library.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the original source package for `ghost`, you just want to test locally, and it is just one file changed then here is what you can do.

**1. Create a diff of your changes:**

```
diff -u /path/to/original_ghost_file.c ghost_file_changes.c > ghost.patch
```

**2. Apply the patch.**

Move into your source directory and run:

```
patch -p1 ghost.patch
```

Without seeing your patch, I can't advise you on what `-p` option to use, but I assuming you used absolute paths.

**3. Rebuild and install**

Still in your source directory, run  `./configure` , `make` , and `make check`. If you want to replace the original version of `ghost` then run `make install` lastly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but the above doesn't work. In step 2, I think we need to do ($patch -p1 < /path/to/ghost.patch ). Also, my ./configure doesn't work! I had to do --disable-sanity-checks which messed up everything.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I will edit the answer. Can you post the output of running ./configure without disabling the sanity checks?

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. Here is what I did after I installed Ubuntu-12.04 on Virtual Box, all from my home directory. 1- ($sudo apt-get install alien) 2- ($sudo apt-get install gawk) 3- ($apt-get source libc6) 4- ($diff -u eglibc-2.15/nss/digits_dots.c ghost_file_changes.c > ghost.patch) 5- ($patch -p1 < ghost.patch) This gave me an error so I had to do ($patch -p0 < ghost.patch). Finally I got a message (patching file ghost_file_changes.c) . 6-($mkdir eglibc-2.15-build) . 7-($cd eglibc-2.15-build) . 8-($../eglibc-2.15/configure).

Comment: Then it typed this message (*** On GNU/Linux systems the GNU C Library should not be installed into
*** /usr/local since this might make your system totally unusable.
*** We strongly advise to use a different prefix. For details read the 
FAQ.
*** If you really mean to do this, run configure again using the extra
*** parameter `--disable-sanity-checks'.
)