# How to perform binary diffing and patching with standard Ubuntu (Debian) tools?

Tags: scripts, debian, patch, binary, diff

I have two set of binary files (before and after a certain operation), and I need to perform diffing betwen the sets, and patching on the first set in order to obtain the second set.

How can I perform the patching using preinstalled Ubuntu (or better, Debian) tools?

I'm not concerned about how to produce the diff, since it's on my dev machine, but patching is performed on machines that are basic Ubuntu/Debian machines.

I'm aware of `bspatch`, but it is not preinstalled.

- Clarification 1: *binary* implies that the standard `diff`/`patch` tools can't be used;
- Clarification 2: `using preinstalled tools` implies that no packages can be installed.

Comment: is it okay to install a package using `sudo apt install package`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a patch for C Library](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902641/how-to-make-a-patch-for-c-library)

Comment: @Panther as explained in the question, the target are binary files, not text files (as in the mentioned link)

Comment: @Yaron no, otherwise, as I wrote, bsdiff/bspatch would solve the problem.

Comment: Your restriction to out-of-the box utilities sounds arbitrary and like an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). Why this restriction? Why is the package manager, the standard method to overcome it, unsatisfying? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: There are a few reasons to avoid download: 1. distribution tools dependency; if this operation can be done with standard Ubuntu/Debian (/POSIX) tools, possibly it can be done with other distros (Red Hat derivatives); 2. packaging tools dependency; downloading packages is again distribution dependent, so if the product should ship to different distros, it would require support for other package managers; 3. user consent; if the product doesn't download anything, the UX is better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on the exact interpretation of `using standard [...] tools`, a valid and very platform independent solution is to download and build bspatch on the target machines.

bspatch has no dependencies;  it simply requires gcc (which is preinstalled at least on Ubuntu):

```
wget https://github.com/mendsley/bsdiff/archive/master.zip -O /tmp/bsdiff-master.zip
unzip /tmp/bsdiff-master.zip -d /tmp
cd /tmp/bsdiff-master
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

and `/tmp/bsdiff-master/bspatch` is ready for use.

Comment: This breaks your 'out of the box'-requirement. Debian does not come with gcc in base install. OpenSUSE does not come with gcc. Raspbian does not... the list goes on. But all those distros do have bsdiff in their repositories, and it would be easier to explain to the user that she would have to install bsdiff than this...